# How to Store Balance in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

What is the best way to store customer balance in MySQL.

I am creating an accounting application and I am faced with the decision whether to save each customers account balance in a table row or  calculate it when needed.

I would like to know the best approach and why it is the better method.

Comment: Can you give some more detail.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

The advantage of always calculating the balance is that the balance will always be correct.  The disadvantage is that account balances can take a long time to calculate, and you'll have to make the calculation every time you need the value.

The advantage of storing the balance is that retrieving the balance is more or less instantaneous.  The disadvantage is that, if you're not careful, the balance can go stale; that is, it won't reflect the *actual* balance.  Storing the balance requires that you always keep it maintained as the correct value when anything that might affect the balance (sales, returns, payments, etc) changes.

Think of a stored balance as a *cached value,* with all of the advantages and problems it entails.

If you do store the balance, it should be updated in a database transaction along with the thing that is changing the balance.  That way, you won't have problems with race conditions where someone retrieves an old balance, but the new item that changes the balance has already been recorded.

Comment: Thanks, I personally prefer to calculate when needed, but I was just faced with a doubt whether I have been using the right/ best approach

Comment: Another advantage of always calculating the balance is that your database will be in third normal form. Rule is "Don't use columns that are not fully dependent upon the primary key" Check this site http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/3nf.htm

Answer (score 4):

you should store all of the transactions rather than just the current balance. That way you have history, and you can run different aggregates on it rather than just "final balance."

and

Use decimal(10,2). float is susceptible to rounding errors, see here "http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html"

Comment: Plus one for pointing out the possibility of rounding errors.

Comment: using decimal(10,2) is probably safer way , since its doesn't goes for round-off

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your problem. I recently designed the same thing, so what I did is:

Created a table `user_account` that has `one-to-one` relation with `user` table. This `user_account` holds 'quick' information related to user balance like remaining balance, last update, expiry date etc.

I also created a table `transaction` (linked with `user`, `user_account` or may be `order` table) that hold all the transactions against user account. Lets say a `user` bought something today cost 20$ i am saving all these details in `transaction` table. So that in any point of time I can track when and why a user used his/her balance and where.

So there was a reason of using `quick information` word for `user_account` table. What i meant by this was, if you just quickly want current remaining balance of a user, just query `user_account` table to get balance of that particular user but if you want high level details like when and where he/used credit query `transaction` table.

Comment: Is it a good thing to tables with one-to-one relationship

Comment: Yes, I'm considering user's account as a separate entity. So that in future if I need to add more details related to user's account say "Allow negative balance", i'll do that in `user_account` table.